# Cannot use cookie service as a token getter

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, angular2-services

My NgModule can't detect my imported cookieService. It raises an cannot read property error. I don't know where i've gone wrong.
This is my current code in my app.module.ts

```
export function getAuthHttp(http: Http) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    noJwtError: true,
    globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
    tokenGetter: (() => this.CookieService.get('tokenId')),
  }), http);
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
    providers: [
      CookieService, // For cookies
      { // interceptors
        provide: AuthHttp,
        useFactory: getAuthHttp,
        deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
      },
      {
        provide: RequestOptions,
        useClass: HttpOptions
      },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

my error is
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbGEk.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the CookieService.

```
export function getAuthHttp(http: Http) {
  var cookieService = new CookieService();

  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    noJwtError: true,
    globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
    tokenGetter: (() => cookieService.get('tokenId')),
  }), http);
}
```

Comment: in the cookie service i've got an error "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0". In this line: 
var cookieService = new CookieService();

Comment: That is because you have a constructor in your `CookieService` and it is expecting 1 parameter. It is better to define this function `getAuthHttp` into service that has `constructor` and then define your cookieService like - `constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}`

Comment: But how can i import the getAuthHttp in the NgModule
`{ // interceptors
        provide: AuthHttp,
        useFactory: getAuthHttp,
        deps: [Http]
      },`

Comment: It is hard for me to understand what are you trying to do. Here is documentation that I recommend you to read - [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action), [Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), [HttpInterceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#advanced-usage), [RouteGuards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)